# JSP with IntelliJ

Tags: spring, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Since a while I started to use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse. I created my project from Eclipse (where it was working) in IntelliJ and I can start the Spring Boot Application. As a Front-end I use JSP files, but when I open the project in my browser it shows only the HTML code, not the actual website. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: How did you create the Intellij project?

Comment: did you try New>Open From Existing Source in IntelliJ?

Comment: You can easily do this if you have IntelliJ Ultamite.

Answer (score 11):

I am aware that this thread is 3 years old, but since I'm currently working on something similar (spring boot + web application + jsp + intellij ultimate as IDE), wanted to share my experience...

1. created spring **web** application using spring initializr (provided
   inside intellij IDEA)
2. created *webapp* folder under *src/main*
3. opened project structure window (ctrl-shift-alt), selected modules under project settings
4. in the middle window pane, selected Web
5. added newly created folder (src/main/webapp) under "web resources
   directory"
6. applied changes

After that, in my "left click - new" drop down menu, jsp files were also provided...

My current Intellij IDEA Ultimate version is 2020.1

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is the only solution that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar kind of issue earlier. I have solved it by adding the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have created a project sometime ago to cover this issue. The link to the project is mentioned below. Please refer it. I wish it will help you.
[Spring Boot Maven Webapp](https://github.com/kasundm5566/Spring-Boot-Maven-Webapp)

Answer (score 0):

Though this thread is 5 years old, I solved it for IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 version by following the steps:

1. Created spring web application using spring initializer.
2. Created *webapp* folder under *src/main*
3. Opened project structure window (Ctrl+alt+shift+S) or, go to *File>Project Structure*
4. Then select *Project Settings* and select *Facets* under the project settings  option
5. Select the *Web* section and then the *Web with main* option.
6. Add newly created folder (*src/main/webapp*) under "*Web Resources Directory*"
7. Click Apply then OK

Now, right-click on your *webapp* folder and select New and you will see the JSP file option there.

[image]